# Como migrar un hosting de site5 a godaddy?

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, godaddy

Buen dia, se me presento un problema ya que nunca he hecho esto antes, el problema se presenta que la pagina web esta desarrollado en wordpress con un hosting en sites 5, ahora se compro un nuevo en godaddy pero el problema es, como cambio todo lo que tengo de mi pagina web a ese nuevo hosting con el mismo dominio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes pedir el AuthCode en tu servidor actual, es un código para traspasar el dominio de un proveedor a otro. Una vez lo tienes, lo debes proporcionar a tu nuevo proveedor para que hagan la transferencia del dominio.

Te recomiendo hacer una copia de toda tu web. Descarga tus ficheros al ordenador y una vez te hayan traspasado podrás subir los ficheros al nuevo alojamiento. De todas maneras GoDaddy tiene que ayudarte en ello.

Haciendo una búsqueda por internet tienen este apartado: [Cómo transferir su alojamiento](https://es.godaddy.com/help/como-transferir-su-alojamiento-a-nosotros-6429).